# Spanner Emulator - Caller is missing IAM permission spanner.sessions.create on resource

Tags: google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-spanner-emulator

While trying to execute a query on local emulator using Java client API, I am getting the following error -

```
com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerException: PERMISSION_DENIED: com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Caller is missing IAM permission spanner.sessions.create on resource projects/test-project/instances/test-instance/databases/testdatabase.
```

How can I provide this user the capability to create a session on local spanner emulator?

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud Spanner emulator does not implement any IAM and requires you to connect to it **without** any credentials, so this error seems at first sight to indicate that either:

1. You are not connected to the emulator after all, and this error is coming from a the real Cloud Spanner.
2. You have connected to the emulator **with** credentials.

Would you mind sharing the part of your code that is creating the connection?

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure that you've followed the [following steps](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/java#before-you-begin) to configure your local environment appropriately. Basically make sure that all the Cloud Spanner related APIs are enabled and run the following command:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

By making sure that the account used for authentication has a role with enough permissions as described on the [Access Control documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/iam). The [Cloud Spanner Database Admin](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/iam#spanner.databaseAdmin) should allow you to issue your query, but you can create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/iam#custom-roles) if you think that the permissions granted by the mentioned predefined role are too much.

The [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/emulator#using_the_gcloud_cli_with_the_emulator) advises to create a separate [gcloud configuration](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/emulator#using_the_gcloud_cli_with_the_emulator) and making sure that you set the `SPANNER_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable is set in the following way (check the correct info [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/emulator#client-libraries):

```
export SPANNER_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9010
```

Comment: I followed all instructions, but I forgot to export the variable SPANNER_EMULATOR_HOST

Comment: No IAM roles should be required for the emulator

Comment: @Guergolet, i followed the mentioned steps for CloudSpanner Emulator but could not succeed. I verified the host value  is set in Command line and Emulator is running on the ports as well. I received the error below 'google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Either caller is missing IAM permission spanner.databases.create on resource projects/adhi-gcloud-project/instances/test-instance, or the CreateDatabaseRequest.create_statement field is malformed and the database name could not be identified to verify Cloud IAM Conditions'